# RegGetValue Question

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

I'm trying to write(what I thought would be) a simple script in C++ to search through the registry(SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall specifically) and return the value of the DisplayName value.

I have gone through the MSDN docs, and hours of searching on google, unfortunately I'm stuck.

```
#define BUFFER 8192
char value[255];
DWORD BufferSize = BUFFER;

if(RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    _T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"),
    _T("DisplayName"),
    RRF_RT_ANY,
    NULL,
    (PVOID)&value,
    &BufferSize)
    )
{
    _tprintf(TEXT("(%d) %s - %s\n"), i+1, achKey, value);
}
```

Now, I need to be able to append achKey to the 2nd parameter of RegGetValue, so that it grabs the correct values when looping through each subkey.

I've tried a million different things, unfortunately my experience in C++ is pretty limited and my google skills apparently need some work as well.

Edit:
achKey is the name of the key:
Ex: NVIDIA Drivers

So when appended, the 2nd param should read:

```
SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\NVIDIA Drivers
```

Here's the MSDN reference on RegGetValue:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I have also tried something like:

```
wcscat(_T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"), achKey)
```

It will compile, but then when run, it crashes.

Comment: Indent with 4 spaces to make a code block, don't use `<pre>` or `<code>`.

Comment: What is achKey? I suppose that is name of key that is matched?

Comment: @Burgos - Yessir, it's the name of the key.

Comment: Stick with C++ strings instead of char[] : std::string (or std::wstring for unicode). The only thing then that you need to worry about is that Windows API calls like `RegGetValue` live in an older, brain-damaged world. To pass a std::string to these functions, use the `c_str()` method. `std::string foo = "HKLM/.../"; foo = foo + suffix; RegGetValue(..., foo.c_str(), ...)`

Answer (score 6):

There are two main issues with your original code that I can see:

1. **Mixing Unicode/ACSII Strings** : From your comments it appears you are compiling the project with Unicode strings but you are using a `char value[255]`. Use a `wchar_t` or `TCHAR` instead of `char`. the `RegGetValue()` function will be automatically 'forwarded' to the `RegGetValueW()` or `RegGetValueA()` functions depending on the project Unicode settings. If you wish to force a particular character set you can use those functions directly but it is generally better to just use the `RegGetValue()` function directly.
2. **Buffer Overflow:** You are use a 255 element char buffer but passing the buffer's size as 8192. If the registry key is more than 255 bytes (not characters) then you'll overflow that buffer and bad things will happen. Make sure you pass the exact buffer size or smaller. Also be aware of the differences between bytes and characters with Unicode strings. Some functions may expect or return a buffer size in bytes and some in characters.

The following code is an example of using wide-strings in the manner you desire:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    ...
std::wstring BaseKey(_T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"));
std::wstring achKey(_T("DisplayName"));
std::wstring NewKey;

NewKey = BaseKey + achKey;
wcout << NewKey << _T("\n");
NewKey = BaseKey + _T("AnotherName");
wcout << NewKey << _T("\n");
```

**Edit: LPCWSTR Notes**

A `LPCWSTR` in Windows is simple a pointer to a constant wide string, or more directly a `const wchar_t *` which is the same thing as a `TCHAR *` in a Unicode project. Note that if you changed your project to a MultiByte character set then the function declaration of `RegGetValue()` (and a host of other Windows functions) would change to using a `LPCSTR` instead and a `TCHAR` would simply be a `char`.

The nice thing about using std::string/wstring is that they are directly compatible with a `LPCWSTR` and a `LPCSTR`. Thus your call to `RegGetValue()` can use the std::wstring variables directly like:

```
std::wstring BaseKey(_T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"));
std::wstring Value(_T("DisplayName"));
RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, BaseKey, Value, ...).
```

Comment: Ok, I think we're on the right track. achKey is not something I'm defining. It is the subKey name variable. achKey is a TCHAR. So how would I go about concatenating:

    std::wstring BaseKey(_T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"));

and a TCHAR variable.

I apologize in advance if my errors are simple, I have almost no experience in C++, just PHP. But I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now.

Comment: Also I should mention that the 2nd parameter in RegGetValue must be LPCWSTR.

Answer (score 0):

> I have also tried something like:
>
> ```
> wcscat(_T("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\"), achKey)
> ```
>
> It will compile, but then when run, it
>   crashes.

That's because you are trying to concatenate something onto a literal string, so the best that will happen is you will trample over random areas of your application. I'm a little surprised it compiles without errors or warnings, as the literal string would be const...?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x0y282%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

What you're looking at here is pretty basic string manipulation. Something like:

```
std::string path("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\");
std::string achKey = get_key();

RegGetValueEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, (path+achKey).c_str(), /* ... */);
```

If you're using wide strings, you want to use `wstring` (and wide character literals) instead:

```
std::wstring path(L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\");

std::wstring achKey = get_key(); // some function that gets the key you care about.

RegGetValueEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, (path+achKey).c_str(), /* ... */);
```

Comment: I don't know the name of the subkey ahead of time unfortunately. I need to be able to append the variable, "achKey" to SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\

Comment: Also, trying to do path + "Text Here" isn't valid(neither is path+achKey), "no suitable conversion function from std:: to "LPCWSTR" exists"

Comment: @Josh: if you're using wide strings, you'd want `std::wstring` instead. Then `path+achKey` should be valid (well, it really *shouldn't* be valid, nor should anything else using that cursed HN crap, but it is anyway).

Comment: I tried wstring, no dice as well. Won't even compile. I have searched google over and over for a way to concatenate a text macro string and a tchar variable. Nothing has worked, nor have I even found someone trying to do it.

Comment: You need `.c_str()` on the resulting string it order to pass it to a function expecting a pointer to the string.  There's no implicit conversion like there is with MFC or ATL CStrings.